# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

*Yes, I have checked the other questions regarding the same problem, but none of them match my specific problem, so I hope someone can help me out here.*

So, I have a button:

```
<input type="button" class="operator" value="/" />
```

And when I click it, I get the error mentioned in the title. The function it calls:

```
function operators(origVal) {
                var Oper = "";
                Oper = ($(this).val());
                console.log(Oper, origVal);       
            };
```

origVal is just a number I pass when I call the function.

So yeah, everything works perfect when I reduce the function to

```
function operators(origVal) {
                var Oper = "";
                console.log(Oper,origVal);       
            };
```

EDIT: The part that was here was not my code and seems to cause some confusion and wasting your time trying to figure it out.

Comment: where does that variable `elem` comes from.?

Comment: did you try it with any other value then a slash? they do tend to cause problems sometimes when used as strings

Comment: try a console.log(this) - to check waht this realy is ;-)

Comment: How do you call `operators`? That is key to the answer!

Comment: $(".operator").click(function () {
                operators(CurVal)
            });


like this. Before I just did $(".operator").click(operators); and that gave the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function creates a new scope, so inside

```
function operators(origVal) {
    console.log(this); // returns the scope of the function

    // "this" is the function, or more likely the window in this case, 
    // and it has no val() method
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B9byh/)

`this` is not what you think it is, and it certainly has no value property, and that is what is causing the error, see the Fiddle.

If you where to use jQuery event handlers, the scope would be set for you

```
$('.operator').on('click', operators);
```

then `this` inside the function would be the bound element.

**EDIT:**

If the function is called within the event handler, you can do

```
$(".operator").click(function () { 
    operators.apply(this, [CurVal]);
});
```

The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

The syntax of `apply()` is almost identical to that of `call()`, the fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an argument list, while `apply()` accepts a single array of arguments.

**[More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**

Comment: I'm lost. Doesn't this refer to the button, on which was clicked?

 $(".operator").click(function () {
                operators(CurVal)
            });

this is how it is called

Comment: Nope, the scope isn't set when called that way, then you'd have to pass the element as well.

Comment: @Zeretil - edited the answer, and provided a solution for that.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying! Why are you putting CurVal between brackets? why are you using apply ? Is it because the function needs to take parameters?

Comment: apply() takes two arguments, the first being the scope, and the second is an array of the arguments passed, that's why it's wrapped in brackets, it has to be an array.

Comment: Adding apply seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you! Can you please explain "this" and the scope a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `$(this)` inside a function call .. i am sure it is a scoping issue...

for `$(this)` to work ,**either use jquery's click event handler** or pass this to the function onclick call

since you haven't showed us , how actaully are you calling the operator function.. assuming this is how you are doing it..

```
  ... onclick="operators(this,somevalue)"..


 function operators(this,origVal)
  {
      var Oper = "";
      Oper = ($(this).val());
      console.log(Oper, origVal); 

  }
```

**updated**

use `call()` or `apply()` to specify `this` context is button here and not function itself

```
$(".operator").click(function () {
   operators.call( this, CurVal ); 
}
```

Comment: OP could proxify context on calling function too, using $.proxy() jquery method or bind() or call() or apply() in javascript

Comment: What is proxifying content?                          And bipen, I use this on multiple other occasions in my code and it never gives an error.